# Best way (if any) to hook a generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-decorators

I'm writing a very simple decorator to give me some basic debug information about a function.

```
from functools import wraps
from time import perf_counter

class debug(object):
    def __init__(self, Time=False, Parameters=False, Doc=False):
        self.t = Time
        self.p = Parameters
        self.d = Doc

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def run(*args, **kwargs):
            params = ""
            if self.p:
                params = ", ".join(["{}".format(arg) for arg in args] + ["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])
            print("\n\tDebug output for '{}({})'".format(func.__name__, params))
            if self.d:
                print('\tDocstring: "{}"'.format(func.__doc__))
            if self.t:
                t1 = perf_counter()
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.t:
                t2 = perf_counter()
                print("\tTime Taken: {:.3e} seconds".format(t2 - t1))
            print("\tReturn Type: '{}'\n".format(type(val).__name__))
            return val
        return run
```

This is all well and good for normal functions.

```
@debug(Parameters=True, Time=True, Doc=True)
def foo(i, j=5):
    """Raises i to 2j"""
    for _ in range(j):
        i **= 2
    return i

i = foo(5, j=3)
# Output:
"""
    Debug output for 'foo(5, j=3)'
    Docstring: "Raises i to 2j"
    Time Taken: 1.067e-05 seconds
    Return Type: 'int'
"""
```

However, generators are a different story.

```
@debug(Parameters=True, Time=True, Doc=True)
def bar(i, j=2):
    """Infinite iterator of increment j"""
    while True:
        yield i
        i += j

b = bar()  # Output occurs here
next(b) # No output
```

Now, from what I have coded, that is completely expected, but I'm wondering how I can hook the `.__next__()` method or what the best way of going about this is.

Comment: looks like you can use itertools.tee for this case

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your `__call__` method and return a generator if a generator is given as an input (add `import types` at the top of your file):

```
def __call__(self, f):
    if isinstance(f, types.GeneratorType):
        def run_gen(*args, **kwargs):
            # do pre stuff...
            for _ in f(*argw, **kwargs):
                yield _
            # do post stuff...
        return run_gen
    else:
        def run(*args, **kwargs):
            # do pre stuff...
            r = f(*argw, **kwargs)
            # do post stuff...
            return r
        return run
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace function.next as it is a read only value. But you can do something like this (see `debug_generator` function):

from functools import wraps
    import inspect

```
class debug(object):
    def __init__(self, Time=False, Parameters=False, Doc=False):
        self.t = Time
        self.p = Parameters
        self.d = Doc

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def debug_generator(func):
            for i, x in enumerate(list(func)):
                # here you add your debug statements
                print "What you want: step %s" % i
                yield x
        @wraps(func)
        def run(*args, **kwargs):
            params = ""
            if self.p:
                params = ", ".join(["{}".format(arg) for arg in args] + ["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])
            print("\n\tDebug output for '{}({})'".format(func.__name__, params))
            if self.d:
                print('\tDocstring: "{}"'.format(func.__doc__))
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("\tReturn Type: '{}'\n".format(type(val).__name__))

            if inspect.isgenerator(val):
                return debug_generator(val)
            return val
        return run
```

Basically you just get all the value from the generator you want to debug, and then you `yield` them again, adding debug statement in the loop.